# Get the current slide element on change event in OwlCarousel2

Tags: owl-carousel-2

I am trying to create an effect similar to this (the demo uses Bootstrap Carousel):

https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/BpVrXP/

Bootstrap's `'slide.bs.carousel'` returns a `relatedTarget` that is the slide element going to be displayed as soon as the carousel is moved i.e changed to another slide.

I haven't been able to find an equivalent data being returned in OwlCarousel2's `changed.owl.carousel` event. What event, if any, returns the element that's going to be in view?

Is there any alternative way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try the event `translated.owl.carousel`, translated is fired after the animation

Comment: it could be in comment but as you dont have aceess to give comment, please read documentation how to handle this kind of situation if possible